# not break line and max-width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table and it can't break line in any `td`. All `td` has max-width property.

Some `td` text are longer than max-width, and I want to "break" this text  to this max-width, for example:

Text: "this is the text in td"

Text which fits in `td`: "this is"

This is my code:

```css
.nobreaklineClass{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.maxwidthClass{
  max-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="nobreaklineClass">
    <td class="maxwidthClass">"this is the text in td" </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "break"? with `white-space: nowrap` you're telling it specifically *not* to wrap the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the cell:

```css
.nobreaklineClass{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.maxwidthClass{
    max-width: 30px;
    border: 1px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="nobreaklineClass">
      <td class = "maxwidthClass">"this is the text in td" </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

(I added a dotted border to make the cell size clear)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Johannes, but with ellipses:

```css
.nobreaklineClass{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.maxwidthClass{
    max-width: 80px;
    border: 1px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr class="nobreaklineClass">
  <td class = "maxwidthClass">this is the text in td</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```